# Pass JS array to PHP via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an array in javascript and I need to convert it into PHP array. So I have this code and I have tried other codes too but no one has worked.
Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="res" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 400px; height: 200px;"></div>
 <br>
 <input type="file" name="img[]" id="img" multiple>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
 <script>
  var array = new Array();
  $('#img').change(function() {
   var img = $('#img').val().split('\\').pop();
   array.push(img);
   document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = array;
  });
  $('#submit').click(function() {
   var send_data = JSON.stringify(array);
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
    url: "test.php",
    data: {send_data:send_data},
    datatype: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
    }
   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my test.php

```html
<?php 
$data = $_POST['send_data'];
$decoded = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($decoded);
?>
```

Comment: what's the error?...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia code doesn't give back array from PHP code

Comment: try to log in the browser console what's inside the array just before the request

Answer (score 0):

HTML && Javascript sample code:

```js
function validateForm() {
let formData = {
        'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'email': $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'message': $('textarea[name=message]').val()
    };
    //Prevent page from refresh after sending message (ajax)
    $.ajax({
        url: "./assets/php/contact_me.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.code)
                $('#status').text(data.message);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#status').text("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" onclick="validateForm()">Send Message</a>

<!-- Status text -->
<div id="status" class="text-danger pb-2"></div>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
if (strlen($name) < 3){
    print json_encode(array('message' => 'Name is too short', 'code' => 0));
    exit();
}
if ($email === ''){
    print json_encode(array('message' => 'Email cannot be empty', 'code' => 0));
    exit();
} else {
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        print json_encode(array('message' => 'Email format invalid.', 'code' => 0));
        exit();
    }
}
if (strlen($message) < 5){
    print json_encode(array('message' => 'Message is too short', 'code' => 0));
    exit();
}
print json_encode(array('message' => 'successfull!', 'code' => 1));
exit();
```

Comment: this is not what I really need. I can pass variables but I need to pass an array

Comment: in above example "formData" is an array and we are sending it.

Comment: @Matarata ```formData``` is an object not array.

Comment: @JuniusL. Yes. everything is an object but more specific its object of type array.right?

Comment: please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

> I have an array in javascript and I need to convert it into PHP array.

You can transform a javascript array (call it `myDataAsJSArray`) into a **JSON** string, before `POST`-ing:

```
let myDataAsJSON = JSON.stringify('myDataAsJSArray');
```

After `POST`-ing, you can transform the **JSON** string into a **PHP array**:

```
$My_Data_As_PHP_Array = json_decode($_POST['myDataAsJSON'], TRUE);
```

Note that if you omit the optional `TRUE` parameter immediately above, PHP will transform your JSON into a PHP Object, rather than a PHP Array.

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: this is the same way I have done. but this doesn't work!

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I misunderstood your question - are you stuck on the actual data transfer between client and server rather than passing the data between the two languages?

Comment: Yes. The way you told me is one of the most popular once. I have tried it but no result.

Comment: Ok, see. I want to build an admin panel. And fo this I need to enter multiple image files then write some content then add some images and so on. So after this, I want to append all names in one array and then to pass that array into PHP document and upload all those images into a folder. Now I only need to pass js array into PHP

Comment: Yes, I mean just that. I want to transfer data between client and server